# Error in the page of a CPT file in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I have a `CPT` of podcast type implemented in my WordPress.  I had to do a type 301 redirection since the plugin that manages the podcasts (Seriously Simple Podcasting) did not let me modify the appearance of the archive, so I created a custom one and made the aforementioned redirection of podcasts to podcast.

The code that rescues the published podcasts is:

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'podcast',
 'orderby' => 'date',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'posts_per_page'=> '1',
 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
 );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 if( $loop->have_posts() ):

 while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); global $post;
 echo '<div id="podcast_archive">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><div class="img_episode">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, array(200,200) ) . '</div></a>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><h2 class="title_episode">' . get_the_title() . '</h2></a>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><div class="excerpt_episode"><p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p></div></a>' ;
 echo '</div>';

 endwhile;

 next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $loop->max_num_pages );
 previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
 endif;
```

I currently have two chapters published and to prove the paging, I have put each page only contains one episode.

The problem is that when I give `Older entries` he gives me a 404 error. The url he tries to get me out is `https://misitio.com/podcast/page/2/`.

How could I solve this error in paging?  I would not like all episodes to be loaded on the same page.

Comment: sounds like a flush rewrite error. try visiting settings >> permalinks.

Comment: I have emptied the cache of the permalinks and the same 404 error still appears